# creating a table with empty cells (e.g., columns of different length)

Tags: r, dplyr

To communicate the results of my R analysis, I wish create and export a results table with empty cells (see table below).

If I attempt to create a dataframe or tibble in this style, it does not work due to the fact the the columns are of unequal size and therefore return errors. I do not wish to fill in the empty cells with NAs as I can't publish the table with NAs. Is there a way of creating such a table which will only be used for reporting results and not R analysis?

Below is a dummy example of the layout of the results table I wish to create.

I use both base r and tidyverse.

| dataset_name | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 | x7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y1 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 10 |
| y2 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 34 | 12 | 5 | 5 |
| y3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 32 |
| y4 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 45 |  |  |  |
| y5 | 2 | 9 | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| y6 | 6 | 2 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| y7 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| y8 | 90 | 20 | 60 |  |  |  |  |

```
Sample data 

x1 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x2 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x3 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x4 <- sample(1:40, 4)
x5 <- sample(1:40, 3)
x6 <- sample(1:40, 3)
x7 <- sample(1:40, 3)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `gt` package for output tables. Do you have a sample of data you're aiming to do this with? i.e., what input do you aim to get that output from?

Comment: I've added sample data @AndyBaxter. Could you provide an example solution with the GT package?

Comment: Great! have put in an example below using `tidyverse` functions and `gt` to combine these four vectors into a table with blank cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `gt` from the data sample:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

list(
  x1 = sample(1:40, 8),
  x2 = sample(1:40, 8),
  x3 = sample(1:40, 8),
  x4 = sample(1:40, 4),
  x5 = sample(1:40, 3),
  x6 = sample(1:40, 3),
  x7 = sample(1:40, 3)
) |>
  map(`length<-`, 8) |>
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(dataset_name = paste0("y", 1:8)) |> 
  gt() |> 
  cols_move_to_start(dataset_name) |> 
  sub_missing(missing_text = "")
```

| dataset_name | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 | x7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y1 | 20 | 24 | 10 | 15 | 38 | 12 | 23 |
| y2 | 26 | 4 | 30 | 19 | 4 | 37 | 13 |
| y3 | 8 | 16 | 16 | 30 | 5 | 28 | 24 |
| y4 | 38 | 21 | 3 | 20 |  |  |  |
| y5 | 6 | 11 | 33 |  |  |  |  |
| y6 | 11 | 29 | 24 |  |  |  |  |
| y7 | 7 | 13 | 27 |  |  |  |  |
| y8 | 17 | 22 | 28 |  |  |  |  |

Using `` map(`length<-`, 8) `` does expand each to the full length by adding `NA`s, but `sub_missing(missing_text = "")` will then format the output as printing blank cells. You can [output the gt result](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/index.html#export-functions) to a pdf/html/docx file directly or included in an rmarkdown document.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below sample data, you can store them in a list, transform using `lapply`, and then `cbind` via `do.call` to make the desired output:

Data

```
dataset_name <- paste0("y", 1:8)
x1 <- x2 <- x3 <- 1:8
x4 <- 1:4
x5 <- x6 <- x7 <- 1:3
```

Code:

```
l1 <- list(dataset_name, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
l2 <- lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1)))
tble <- do.call(cbind, l2)
tble[is.na(tble)] <- "" # replace NAs with blanks, if desired
```

Output:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,] "y1" "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#[2,] "y2" "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#[3,] "y3" "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#[4,] "y4" "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  ""   ""   ""  
#[5,] "y5" "5"  "5"  "5"  ""   ""   ""   ""  
#[6,] "y6" "6"  "6"  "6"  ""   ""   ""   ""  
#[7,] "y7" "7"  "7"  "7"  ""   ""   ""   ""  
#[8,] "y8" "8"  "8"  "8"  ""   ""   ""   ""
```

If this is not what your data look like, please edit your question to provide sample data and I will update.

Comment: The sample data is fine, however the post requests a solution that does not involve filling the empty cells with NAs as the table could not be published as such.

Comment: @user3200293 Gotcha - see edit, the line `tble[is.na(tble)] <- ""` will replace NAs with blank cells. This will "hard code" it, or alternatively if you are exporting with something like `write.csv` you could add in the command `na = "NA"`

Comment: Great. Would it be possible to add an edit to keep the object name as the column name (e.g., X1, X2...instead of [,1] [,2]?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to convert the `x` variables to character, and append enough
blanks so that they are all the same length.  Here's a function that does that and produces a dataframe:

```r
x1 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x2 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x3 <- sample(1:40, 8)
x4 <- sample(1:40, 4)
x5 <- sample(1:40, 3)
x6 <- sample(1:40, 3)
x7 <- sample(1:40, 3)

ragged <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  lens <- sapply(args, length)
  maxlen <- max(lens)
  args <- lapply(args, function(x) c(as.character(x), rep("", maxlen - length(x))))
  df <- do.call(data.frame, args)
  names(df) <- names
  df
}

ragged(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
#>   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
#> 1 20 23 23 24 17 19 33
#> 2 10  7 38 13 38 22 26
#> 3  7 11 24 17 32 25  4
#> 4 34 24  1 33         
#> 5 25  5 31            
#> 6 19  9 18            
#> 7 32  6 35            
#> 8 28 28  5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `cbind.na`

```
out <- data.frame(dataset_name = paste0("y", 1:8), 
   do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, mget(ls(pattern = '^x\\d+'))))
out[is.na(out)] <- ""
```

-output

```
> out
  dataset_name x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
1           y1 32 19 20 35  8  8 14
2           y2  9  2 35  6 12 11 15
3           y3 31  9 16  5 25 39  9
4           y4 35 35 30 38         
5           y5 34 37 40            
6           y6  2 20 29            
7           y7 22  8 31            
8           y8 21 23 17
```